# iOS center align guide line, when user is dragging UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

I'd like to show center align guide line, when user is dragging UILabel in UIView. So, user can try to set center vertically and horizontally.

I can't find open source and keyword. Is there any open source about center align guide line like snap future.

[image]

Comment: What did you tried already ? Did you tried to manually add constraint when user drags label ?

Comment: Center line guid is already exist

Comment: You mean, you want to do it programmatically ? Like showing a dashed vertical line when user drag some view into another view?

Comment: I guess she is going to build draggable view with center alignment guides when the view reaches near vertically or horizontally center.

It'll be great if this can also have sticky features, lol.

Comment: @AntonMalmygin yes, when user drags label, I'd like to show align guide line in uiview :)

Comment: Did you find a solution for iOS? :)

Comment: @RoiMulia yup, I used Notification when uilabel was center.

Comment: @LucyJeong so the superview observes the notification then shows a dashed line (subview) when the UILabel reaches its center?

Comment: @LucyJeong did you achieve this? if yes, could you provide more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucy. Surprise! How is your trip going in Chiang-Mai?

I suggest you to make your own swift library refer to https://github.com/mrflix/Alignment-Guides

You can also see [demo](http://mrflix.github.io/Alignment-Guides/) for this library.

I believe you can make this library with swift and share through Cocoapod things :)

Have a safe trip!